# Does Big O notation apply to a while(true) loop?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```java
while(true) {
    System.out.println("hola");
    break;
}
```

I have a code snippet here of a `while` loop with `true` condition. I was wondering if big O notation can be applied to this code snippet.

Comment: Please post your code as text. (What would the `n` be in your infinite loop?)

Comment: Depends. `O(∞)` could sometimes be used to express a **program** that doesn't terminate but your loop does terminate and hence in this case is `O(1)`.

Comment: This particular loop only ever executes once. It's basically a noop. The *algorithm* doesn't do anything extra and it doesn't scale with the input in any way. This has zero to do with Big O.

Comment: Please remove the image and post the code as text, this is ugly and not searchable.

Answer (score 5):

Big O notation is a tool we can use for analysing algorithms. The way we apply it is by counting the number of steps that the algorithm takes to execute, expressing this number of steps as a function of the input size *n*, and simplifying the counting/analysis by ignoring constant factors and dominated terms.

For your algorithm, there is no "input" so it is not clear what *n* should refer to, but the number of steps is also fixed; it prints one string of a fixed length, then the `break` statement terminates the loop. So its running time is O(1), i.e. constant.

Generally speaking, the kind of control-flow language constructs you use in the algorithm don't matter (e.g. `while` vs. `for`, vs. tail recursion), because you can just write an equivalent algorithm which does the same thing with different control-flow constructs. An equivalent algorithm will execute with the same number of steps, so changing the syntax in this way doesn't affect the results of the analysis. The [very first algorithm analysis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkUNH9r6UCI) was done by Donald Knuth on [flowcharts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart), which any [control-flow graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph) (including for `while(true)` / `break`) can be transformed into.

Answer (score 2):

Whether the `while` loop has a `true` condition or not tells us nothing, since the loop could contain a `break` statement.  And in fact after the code snippet was added to the question it became apparent that the question was about a `while` loop which breaks on the first iteration, which means that the title of the question was misleading.

So, here is the thing: "while loops with true conditions" are a trivial technicality which is unsuitable in discussions about theoretical concepts such as big-oh notation. In discussions about big-oh notation we do not even want to know what language the algorithm was written in, and whether that language had keywords such as `while`, `true`, and `break`.

All we care about is how the amount of work done by the algorithm varies as the number of input units vary.

In special cases where the number of iterations is not dependent on the size of the input, either because it is infinite or because it is a constant, big-oh is of course still applicable.  Take for example the case of an array lookup, or a hash map lookup, which is well established to be `O(1)`.  Or even the case of a loop that immediately breaks, as the case is with this stackoverflow question.

The case of infinity is a bit weird, and some folks might disagree, but obviously what we have here is an algorithm which will take an infinite amount of time to process a single unit of input. So, if we were interested in that, we would be talking about `O(∞)`.

Comment: I would argue that `O(∞)` has no bearing in regards of **algorithms** since an algorithm is described as `An algorithm is a finite sequence of well-defined, computer-implementable instructions.` and `An algorithm can be expressed within a finite amount of space and time.`. Hence the complexity of an *algorithm* cannot be infinite. A **program** on the other hand can.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen Yours is a valid argument, of course.  Wikipedia and Merriam-Webster seem to include in their definitions of "algorithm" the requirement that it consist of a finite number of steps.  But this may be arbitrary. 
 Oxford and Cambridge do not appear include such a requirement in their definitions of algorithm.

Comment: Infinite loop won't depend over size/scale of input, its execution time is simply infinite, irrespective of anything. As a student with lesser knowledge, I wonder why would Big-O be considered for an infinite loop.

Comment: The infinite while loop **is** expressed in a finite number of steps; the code easily fits on your screen, which has a finite number of pixels. It is the running time which is infinite, not the expression of the algorithm. The rule about "expressed in a finite number of steps" is theoretically needed to exclude algorithms which would "compute" all of the digits of a non-computable number by simply having infinitely many print statements, for example.

Comment: @kaya3 Ah, thanks for shedding light on this. Makes sense. So the proverbial "never ending story" could not possibly be an algorithm, and this is not because the events that it describes never end, but because the narration (the text of the story) does not end.

Comment: @MikeNakis that's an interesting way of putting it, but "could not possibly be" depends on what you mean. For example, `print(1); print(2); print(3); ...` is not an algorithm, but `for i = 1 to infinity: print(i)` is an algorithm which does the same thing. If the never-ending story is too unpredictable for an algorithm to generate its text, then it could not be an algorithm. But predictable stories can be algorithms: *"It was a dark and stormy night; two men stood on a bridge. One man said to the other, 'Antonio, tell me a storio!' And this is what he said: 'It was a dark and stormy night..."*